# `git rebase -i` error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

When running `git rebase -i` I get an error:

```
$ git rebase -i 01a182d66b14ef8f32eb09614fe2c7144044a537^
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        Annotation/README.MD
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
error: could not detach HEAD
```

I don't see what the issue is, since when I run `git status` it tells me there are no unstaged changes:

```
git status
On branch dataset
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Running `git stash` also doesn't help:

```
$ git stash
No local changes to save
```

Answer (score 0):

The final error message (about failing to detach `HEAD`) should just be ignored here; it's an artifact of the earlier error.

The earlier error is pretty straightforward though:

> ```
> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
>        Annotation/README.MD
> ```

This means that *right now*, you have an untracked working tree file named `Annotation/README.md`.  (If you're not sure what "untracked file" and/or "working tree" mean, read [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69572331/1256452) for instance.  Since `git status` is not complaining about it, it seems to be both untracked and ignored.)

Meanwhile, the commit that `git rebase` is first going to check out, so as to copy some other commits, has a file in it named `Annotation/README.MD`.  To check out that commit, Git must check out that file.  Checking out that file will clobber the file named `Annotation/README.MD` that is sitting in your working tree right now.

To avoid losing the contents of the working tree file `Annotation/README.MD`, Git won't *check out* that commit right now.  If you save the file—by adding and committing it—or remove the file entirely or move it out of the way, that will solve the problem:

> ```
> Please move or remove [this file] before you [check out the target commit]
> ```

Since `git rebase` needs to check out the target commit before it can begin the commit-copying process, `git rebase` needs you to do what `git checkout` needs you to do.

Comment: I just want to comment here, that reading your linked response on what untracked files are doesn't seem to help me. Not sure if it did OP. I have no indexed changes or uncommited staged changes, I just checked out a branch, but trying to rebase my main does show me lots of errors on "changed files".

Files that I did not even change on the branch I'm currently at, similar to OP I don't see any files changed on `git status` e.g.